# how to count the number of occurrences of a particular attribute in an xml file?

Tags: xml, database, xquery

Given the following xml file, I need to report the uid of the user who has less than 4 followers and the uid of the followers.

```
<!DOCTYPE users SYSTEM "users.dtd">
<users>
 <user uid = "u1" dob = "06/03/94" email = "tom@hotmail.com">
    <surname> Doe</surname>
    <givennames> Jon </givennames>
    <follows who = "u1 u2"/>
    <playlists>
      <playlist pid = "p1" created ="12/03/11" playcount = "5" /> 
    </playlists>
   </user>

  <user uid = "u2" dob = "06/03/95" email = "jane@hotmail.com">
    <surname> Dod</surname>
    <givennames> Jane </givennames>
    <follows who = "u1 u3"/>
    <playlists>
      <playlist pid = "p2" created ="12/02/10" playcount = "2"/> 
    </playlists>
   </user>

   <user uid = "u3" dob = "06/04/95" email = "dave@hotmail.com">
    <surname> ron</surname>
    <givennames> dave </givennames>
    <follows who = "u1 u2"/>
    <playlists>
      <playlist pid = "p3" created ="12/02/09" playcount = "9"/> 
     </playlists>
   </user>

   <user uid = "u4" dob = "06/04/99" email = "jeff@hotmail.com">
    <surname> dun</surname>
    <givennames> jeff</givennames>
     <follows who = "u1 u2 u3"/>
    <playlists>
      <playlist pid = "p4" created ="12/02/09" playcount = "3"/> 
    </playlists>
   </user>

</users>
```

I need a query which gives the output:

```
<fewfollowers>
    <who uid = "u2">
           <follower uid = "u1"/>
           <follower uid = "u3"/>
           <follower uid = "u4"/>
    </who>
    <who uid = "u3">
           <follower uid = "u2"/>
           <follower uid = "u4"/>
    </who>
    <who uid = "u4">
    </who>
</fewfollowers>
```

!ATTLIST follows who IDREFS #IMPLIED

if the user reported doesn't have any followers, just report their own uid

I've tried utilizing the count() function but i'm not getting anything helpful. I try:

```
for $user in doc("users.xml")/users/user
   return count($user/follows/@who = $user")
```

but this seems to only return the count of @who for each $user and not the particular element. Furthermore, How would i traverse through an IDREFS attribute? they're supposed to be distinguished by a white space but my count function seems to only register it as 1 attribute instead of multiple. I had expected my function to return atleast:

```
 1, 2, 2, 3
```

but it returns:

```
1,1,1,1
```

Comment: cramming multiple ids into an attribute is just a bad design.  Can you change that?

Comment: are you talking about the !ATTLIST follows who IDREFS #implied? if so, I can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @oldProgrammer. You shouldn't be putting the IDs into one attribute but maybe you dont have control over that. If you do just put them into elements so that you dont have to tokenize them.

The reason you are getting the 1,1,1,1 is because your `count` function is doing a compare, it will either be true or false. And that will always be 1. So i think you meant to put a predicate around the `$user` like this `$user/follows/@who[. $user]`. Althought that wont work either because `$user` is the user element.

What I think you are looking for is this line of code

```
fn:count($user/follows/fn:tokenize(@who, ' '))
```

based on the xml you gave us it will return this.

```
2
2
2
3
```

You need to tokenize the who attribute on the white space to get the count of the followers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DTD defines @who as type IDREFS, and @uid as type ID, you should be able to do things like

```
let $followers := idref($user/follows/@who)
return (count($followers) || string-join($followers/email, "; ")
```